# Xamarin Stopwatch is very slow if smartphone is in locked mode

Tags: performance, xamarin, stopwatch

So i have a small xamarin project. Just a little stopwatch:

```
public partial class Stopwatch : ContentPage
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch;
        public Stopwatch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            labeltimer.Text = "00:00:00.00";
        }

        private void btnTimerReset(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Text = "Start";
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }

        private void btnTimerstop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (labeltimer.Text != "00:00:00.00")
                btnStart.Text = "Resume";
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        private void btnTimerStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timerstart();
        }

        private void Timerstart()
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), () =>
            {
                labeltimer.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ff");
                return true; // return true to repeat counting, false to stop timer
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is now, that everything works perfectly, until i start the stopwatch and lock my phone. The stopwatch then works very slow.
Any idea, how to fix that?

Comment: if you lock your phone your app is (likely) being backgrounded and therefore your code is paused

Comment: so what do i need to do so that my code wont get paused when my phone is in locked mode?

Comment: I don't know anything about your app.  You can pause and restart using Forms' lifecycle events.  Or you can look at the various options for running background services that each platform offers.

Comment: you mean this kind of code in App.xaml.cs `   protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }`

Comment: yes, those are the app lifecycle events

Comment: Ok thanks, i am going to try get this done :D

Comment: Nope, i guess onSleep() is not the answer for my problem, i guess i have to look for background services.

Comment: For android, app will get stop when the device is locked and doze will get in doze. So may you need to find the way to keep app alive on each platform. The background service will also stop when the device get into doze.

Comment: Is the foreground service a possible solution to get what i want?

Comment: Yes, foreground service will keep running when the device is locked.